# Task Manager - Sort by average or maximum CPU

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

Very often one wants to sort the processes in task manager according to CPU usage. But CPU usage fluctuate very quickly, so entries on the list jump around and your reading ability will be racing against time before the order switches on you.

Is there a way to sort with respect to average or max cpu usage (in the past 10 seconds, or since opening task manager etc.)

Comment: You could try sorting the processes by CPU time. Or reduce the update frequency.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to sort with respect to average or max cpu usage

Use Admin Tools, Resource Monitor instead. Average CPU is shown  and you can choose your time interval.

Overall, Resource Monitor is better than Task Manager for what you are trying to do.

[image: Resource Monitor]